# How to force Mongoose to ignore __v if passed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Working with mongoose and Express for a basic data endpoint, and I'm having trouble with the `Update` portion of the CRUD operations.

Testing the Update path works in Postman, but when I try from my angular app, it returns this:

> MongoError: Updating the path '__v' would create a conflict at '__v'
>         at C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\techInventory\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\conne
>   ction\pool.js:595:61
>         at authenticateStragglers (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\techInventory\node_modules\mongoose\node_module
>   s\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:513:16)
>         at Connection.messageHandler (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\techInventory\node_modules\mongoose\node_mod
>   ules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:549:5)
>         at emitMessageHandler (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\techInventory\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mo
>   ngodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:309:10)
>         at Socket. (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\techInventory\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mo
>   ngodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:452:17)
>         at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
>         at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
>         at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)
>         at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
>         at TCP.onread (net.js:602:20)

I don't really want to update `__v` but I don't understand why it's being triggered. How can I force it to be ignored?

here's my update method:

```
  update(req,res){
    let _computer = req.body;
    let _id = req.params.computerId;
    Computer.findOneAndUpdate({'_id':_id}, _computer, {upsert: true}, (err, uc) => {
      if(err){
        log.error(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }else{
        res.status(200).send(uc);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is `__v` being sent in the request body?

Comment: yes, and I'm trying to either keep it from being sent to the client on the initial Read request, or delete it before sending the patch request from the client.

Comment: Have you tried `delete _computer.__v` before calling `findOneAndUpdate`? You could also try setting up hooks on your find queries to exclude __v from the returned results so __v never gets to your front end if that applies to your situation.

Comment: @foxinatardis The latter would be ideal. so on my `read()` and `readOne()` handlers just do `delete obj.__v;` before `res.send()`?

Comment: You could do that. I was suggesting a middleware hook which would universally exclude it from find queries. See: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to remove __v from sending by `res.send()`

just add `'-__v'` in `Computer.findOneAndUpdate({'_id':_id},'-__v');`

like

```
 update(req,res){
    let _computer = req.body;
    let _id = req.params.computerId;
    Computer.findOneAndUpdate({'_id':_id},'-__v', _computer, {upsert: true}, (err, uc) => {
      if(err){
        log.error(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }else{
        res.status(200).send(uc);
      }
    });
  }
```

You can also show and hide any field in `.find()` and `findById()`.

To hide use `'-field_name1 , -field_name2'`

like

```
Collection.find({},'-_id -__v');
```

and to show any specific field use `'field_name1 field_name2'`

like

`collection.find({},'name number');`

Comment: One thing though, do you have a link to where filtering like that is discussed? I'm going to try to add this to `.find()` and `.findById()`

Comment: sorry i don't have any link but  i have edited my answer according to your requirement.

Comment: You can see this usage of the 'select' option in the docs here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyid_findById Additionally see the 'select' method on the Query prototype here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in `mongoose@5.0.16`. see [this link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5973#issuecomment-382783002) for more details.

You can also delete `__v` from the `req.body` before updating:

```
if (req.body.__v) {
  Reflect.deleteProperty(req.body, '__v');
}
```